# Getting 400 (Bad Request) making a "POST" using ajax to a rails web site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I've benn trying to make a "Post" using ajax, but I keep getting "400 (Bad Request)". I really don't know if it's the rails website or my ajax request.
the rails it's just a simple scaffold:

```
 # POST /events
 # POST /events.json
def create
 @event = Event.new(event_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: 409 }
  end
end
end


def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :consult, :description, :category, :likes)
end
```

and the ajax that i'm trying to make work:

```
$("button").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/events',

            type: 'POST',
            cache: true,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { event: {  name: "testname", consult: 72, description: "this is a test", category: "dance", likes: 23 } },
            success: function (resp) {

                alert(resp);
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your

`url: http://localhost:3000/events` to `url: http://localhost:3000/events.json`

Then let me know the result.

Thanks